# Lifting a complete monadic action to a transformer (>>= but for Monad Transformers)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I looked hard to see if this may be a duplicate question but couldn't find anything that addressed specifically this. My apologies if there actually is something.

So, I get how `lift` works, it lifts a monadic action (fully defined) from the outer-most transformer into the transformed monad. Cool.

But what if I want to apply a `(>>=)` from one level under the transformer into the transformer? I'll explain with an example.

Say `MyTrans` is a `MonadTrans`, and there is also an instance `Monad m => Monad (MyTrans m)`. Now, the `(>>=)` from this instance will have this signature:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (MyTrans m) where
   (>>=) :: MyTrans m a -> (a -> MyTrans m b) -> MyTrans m b
```

but what I need is something like this:

```
(>>=!) :: Monad m => MyTrans m a -> (m a -> MyTrans m b) -> MyTrans m b
```

In general:

```
(>>=!) :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a -> (m a -> t m b) -> t m b
```

It looks like a combination of the original `(>>=)` and `lift`, except it really isn't. `lift` can only be used on covariant arguments of type `m a` to transform them into a `t m a`, not the other way around. In other words, the following has the wrong type:

```
(>>=!?) :: Monad m => MyTrans m a -> (a -> m b) -> MyTrans m b
x >>=!? f = x >>= (lift . f)
```

Of course a general `colift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a -> m a` makes absolutely zero sense, because surely the transformer is doing something that we cannot just throw away like that in all cases.

But just like `(>>=)` introduces contravariant arguments into the monad by ensuring that they will always "come back", I thought something along the lines of the `(>>=!)` function would make sense: Yes, it in some way makes an `m a` from a `t m a`, but only because it does all of this within `t`, just like `(>>=)` makes an `a` from an `m a` in some way.

I've thought about it and I don't think `(>>=!)` can be in general defined from the available tools. In some sense it is more than what `MonadTrans` gives. I haven't found any related type classes that offer this either. `MFunctor` is related but it is a different thing, for changing the inner monad, but not for chaining exclusively transformer-related actions.

By the way, here is an example of why you would want to do this:

EDIT: I tried to present a simple example but I realized that that one could be solved with the regular `(>>=)` from the transformer. My real example (I think) cannot be solved with this. If you think every case can be solved with the usual `(>>=)`, please do explain how.

Should I just define my own type class for this and give some basic implementations? (I'm interested in `StateT`, and I'm almost certain it can be implemented for it) Am I doing something in a twisted way? Is there something I overlooked?

Thanks.

EDIT: The answer provided by Fyodor matches the types, but does not do what I want, since by using `pure`, it is ignoring the monadic effects of the `m` monad. Here is an example of it giving the wrong answer:

Take `t` = `StateT Int` and `m` = `[]`.

```
x1 :: StateT Int [] Int
x1 = StateT (\s -> [(1,s),(2,s),(3,s)])

x2 :: StateT Int [] Int
x2 = StateT (\s -> [(1,s),(2,s),(3,s),(4,s))])

f :: [Int] -> StateT Int [] Int
f l = StateT (\s -> if (even s) then [] else (if (even (length l)) then (fmap (\z -> (z,z+s)) l) else [(123,123)]))
```

`runStateT (x1 >>= (\a -> f (pure a))) 1` returns `[(123,123),(123,123),(123,123)]` as expected, since both `1` is odd and the list in `x1` has odd length.

But `runStateT (x2 >>= (\a -> f (pure a))) 1` returns `[(123,123),(123,123),(123,123),(123,123)]`, whereas I would have expected it to return `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]`, since the `1` is odd and the length of the list is even. Instead, the evaluation of `f` is happening on the lists `[(1,1)]`, `[(2,1)]`, `[(3,1)]` and `[(4,1)]` independently, due to the `pure` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be very trivially implemented via `bind` + `pure`. Consider the signature:

```
(>>=!) :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => t m a -> (m a -> t m a) -> t m a
```

If you use `bind` on the first argument, you get yourself a naked `a`, and since `m` is a `Monad`, you can trivially turn that naked `a` into an `m a` via `pure`. Therefore, the straightforward implementation would be:

```
(>>=!) x f = x >>= \a -> f (pure a)
```

And because of this, `bind` is always strictly more powerful than your proposed new operation `(>>=!)`, which is probably the reason it doesn't exist in the standard libraries.

---

I think it may be possible to propose more clever interpretations of `(>>=!)` for some specific transformers or specific underlying monads. For example, if `m ~ []`, one might imagine passing the whole list as `m a` instead of its elements one by one, as my generic implementation above would do. But this sort of thing seems too specific to be implemented in general.

If you have a very specific example of what you're after, and you can show that my above general implementation doesn't work, then perhaps I can provide a better answer.

---

Ok, to address your actual problem from the comments:

> I have a function `f :: m a -> m b -> m c` that I want to transform into a function `ff :: StateT s m a -> StateT s m b -> StateT s m c`

I think looking at this example may illustrate the difficulty better. Consider the required signature:

```
liftish :: Monad m => (m a -> m b -> m c) -> StateT m a -> StateT m b -> StateT m c
```

Presumably, you'd want to keep the effects of `m` that are already "imprinted" within the `StateT m a` and `StateT m b` parameters (because if you don't - my simple solution above will work). To do this, you can "unwrap" the `StateT` via `runStateT`, which will get you `m a` and `m b` respectively, which you can then use to obtain `m c`:

```
liftish f sa sb = do
  s <- get
  let ma = fst <$> runStateT sa s
      mb = fst <$> runStateT sb s
  lift $ f ma mb
```

But here's the trouble: see those `fst <$>` in there? They are throwing away the resulting state. The call to `runStateT sa s` results not only in the `m a` value, but also in the new, modified state. And same goes for `runStateT sb s`. And presumably you'd want to get the state that resulted from `runStateT sa` and pass it to `runStateT sb`, right? Otherwise you're effectively dropping some state mutations.

But you can't get to the resulting state of `runStateT sa`, because it's "wrapped" inside `m`. Because `runStateT` returns `m (a, s)` instead of `(m a, s)`. If you knew how to "unwrap" `m`, you'd be fine, but you don't. So the only way to get that intermediate state is to run the effects of `m`:

```
liftish f sa sb = do
  s <- get
  (c, s'') <- lift $ do
    let ma = runStateT sa s
    (_, s') <- ma
    let mb = runStateT sb s'
    (_, s'') <- mb
    c <- f (fst <$> ma) (fst <$> mb)
    pure (c, s'')
  put s''
  pure c
```

But now see what happens: I'm using `ma` and `mb` twice: once to get the new states out of them, and second time by passing them to `f`. This may lead to double-running effects or worse.

This problem of "double execution" will, I think, show up for any monad transformer, simply because the transformer's effects are always wrapped inside the underlying monad, so you have a choice: either drop the transformer's effects or execute the underlying monad's effects twice.

Comment: Indeed the signature matches, and that is relevant because it means that there is something else that I am looking for in my particular case, even if I don't know yet why.

The implementation is not what I want, though. By using `pure`, you're in some way not using the potential ways in which the function `f` may look at the monadic aspects of its argument.

Example I worked through coming in next comment.

Comment: Please put the example in the question itself. Comments are terrible for this.

Comment: Adding in question.

Comment: Your example is exactly what the second half of my answer addresses. The short answer is: I think it's way too specific to be generally useful. If I have enough time, I'll try to expand on why I think that later.

Comment: You're right. I read it but didn't add it up. My specific example is too complicated, specially since this is not my actual problem, rather an obstacle on the way of a potential solution to my problem.

My real problem is that I have a `StateT` transformation over a custom monad `m`, and I have a function `f :: m a -> m b -> m c` that I want to transform into a function `ff :: StateT s m a -> StateT s m b -> StateT s m c`. If it was a one argument function, `hoist` would do the job, but, "hoisting twice" will not even close to do the job. Combining `(>>=!)` with `hoist` would go around this.

Comment: I added another section, please check it out.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `(ra,s') <- ma` and `(rb,s'') <- mb`, respectively, and then use `ra` and `rb` instead of doing `fst`? In any case, I do not think your original solution produced double-running effects, because yes, you used `ma` and `mb` twice, but in alternative data-flows, never monadically composed with themselves.

In fact that would not happen because the argument types for the monads would not match, and in my case it would make absolutely no sense to be able to "run them twice".

There is yet another twist to my real example that I forgot, but I'll leave that out of here.

Comment: No, I can't use `ra` and `rb` instead of `fst <$>`, because `ra` and `rb` are of the wrong type. I would have to use `f (pure ra) (pure rb)`, in which case we're right back to the very first simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you "really want" is

```
(>>>==) :: MyTrans m a -> (forall b. m b -> MyTrans n b) -> MyTrans n a
-- (=<<) = flip (>>=) is nicer to think about, because it shows that it's a form of function application
-- so let's think about
(==<<<) :: (forall a. m b -> MyTrans n b) -> (forall a. MyTrans m a -> MyTrans n a)
-- hmm...
type (~>) a b = forall x. a x -> b x
(==<<<) :: (m ~> MyTrans n) -> MyTrans m ~> MyTrans n
-- look familiar?
```

That is, you are describing monads on the category of monads.

```
class MonadTrans t => MonadMonad t where
    -- returnM :: m ~> t m
    -- but that's just lift, therefore the MonadTrans t superclass
    -- note: input must be a monad homomorphism or else all bets are off
    -- output is also a monad homomorphism
    (==<<<) :: (Monad m, Monad n) => (m ~> t n) -> t m ~> t n

instance MonadMonad (StateT s) where
    -- fairly sure this is lawful
    -- EDIT: probably not
    f ==<<< StateT x = do
        (x, s) <- f <$> x <$> get
        x <$ put s
```

However, making your example work is just not going to happen. It is too unnatural. `StateT Int []` is the monad for programs that nondeterministically evolve the state. It is an important property of that monad that each "parallel universe" receives no communication from the others. The specific operation you are performing will probably not be provided by *any* useful typeclass. You can only do part of it:

```
f :: [] ~> StateT Int []
f l = StateT \s -> if odd s && even (length l) then fmap (\x -> (x, s)) l else []

f ==<<< x1 = []
f ==<<< x2 = [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]
```

Comment: I'm still processing this answer but just so you know. The monad in the category of monads already exists: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html (class `MMonad`)

I have been looking at that all day long, trying to see if it works for me. One reason I didn't dig in too deep in it is that there is no predefined implementation for `StateT`, but you just provided one!

The example I wrote may not work because, as you said, it is too strange, but it may well solve my actual real problem, which is not so convoluted, even if larger. Still thinking.

Comment: Oh, whoops. If that package doesn't define an instance then that probably means there is no lawful one. The one here is probably broken, then.